# node.JS / Django - configure Apache / NGINX to run from location

Tags: node.js, django, apache, nginx

I am using Apache as my frontend VPS / NGINX as backend VPS for node.js / django apps with react.js frontend.

I am trying to run my apps from same VPS, but from different locations:
e.g.:

```
https://myapps/app1
https://myappps/app2
```

Previously I have tackled this issue by adding the location in the router of the apps - however I am not sure if this is the best way to do this. Can I actually add the location in the VPS config of NGINX or Apache?

```
# nginx.default

server {
    listen 8020;
    server_name example.org;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
    location /static {
        root /opt/app/client/build/;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running two node apps it could be done using this NGINX config. Just make sure app1 and app2 are on different ports.

```
server {
        listen 80;

        server_name localhost;

        location /app1 {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        location /app2{
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5001;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
    }
```

EDIT: This is how I have multiple sites running *note: server name should be set to the domain, but if you dont have access to domains set them as the IP:PORT shown in example below! Reason why server name cannot be local is it needs to be public for access. In my use case for website 1 server_name is website1.com then website 2 server_name is website2.com (My domains)

```
server {
        listen 5000;
        //APP 1
        server_name 10.0.0.1:5000;

        location /{
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
    }
    
    server {
        listen 5001;
        //APP 2
        server_name 10.0.0.1:5001;

        location /{
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5001;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This works for my landing page: ```http://localhost:8020/npt/#/```, but if I make another request ```http://localhost:8020/users/signin```, it cannot find the location. I think the request should have been ```http://localhost:8020/npt/users/signin```. How can I do this without adding the location in the app router?

Comment: This can be done in the server name if you are trying to run multiple sites ill edit my answer above.

Comment: thanks for the answers! but now, I think I am missing the location in the URL request? this is what I am trying to achieve: ```http://localhost:8020/npt/#/users/signin``` to ```http://localhost:5000/#/users/signin```.

Comment: The location will be on root of that port http://IP:8020/users/signin

Comment: Did you get it to work with this solution ? @AlexBran

Comment: sorry for my late reply. the method with the servername works, the other one does not work. If gets stuck not having the location in the URL request.

Comment: Server name is the best option its what I use, I should have said that in the first answer! Glad I could help you :)